# Ansible git clone 'Permission Denied' but direct git clone working

Tags: git, ansible

I got a troubling issue with Ansible. I setup a git cloning on my environment using ssh key of my current host:

```
- name: Add user Public Key
    copy: 
     src: "/Users/alexgrs/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
     dest: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
     mode: 0644

- name: Add user Private Key
    copy: 
     src: "/Users/alexgrs/.ssh/id_rsa"
     dest: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa"
     mode: 0600

- name: Clone Repository
  git: 
   repo: repo.git
   dest: /home/vagrant/workspace/
   update: true
   accept_hostkey: true
   key_file: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

If I `vagrant ssh` on Vagrant and execute `git pull repo`it works. But when I do a `vagrant provision` I got the following error message:

```
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I'm pretty sure my publickey is not used by vangrant provision but I'm not able to detect why.

Did you already see this kind of issue ?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
It seems that ansible is not doing a git clone but is trying the following command:

`/usr/bin/git ls-remote ssh://repo.git -h refs/heads/HEAD`

I tried it in my vagrant box and I have the same permission denied issue.

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: You might be having the same problem (with SSH agent forwarding) mentioned in issues [#1303](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1303) and [1735](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735). If you're using Vagrant ~1.4.x (such as the package from the Ubuntu 14.04 repos), you'll likely find some relief by updating to 1.7.x versions of both Ansible and Vagrant. (A Ruby library dependency seems to be [at the root of the problem](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735#issuecomment-38764600).) Updating to the newest Vagrant .deb package from vagrantup.com fixed this for me.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to clone your repository with a public key: `key_file: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`. It should be your private key.

Answer (score 13):

Copying private keys IMHO never is a good idea. A better option would be to enable [ssh agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html).

You can do this globally in your local `.ssh/config`:

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

Or in your `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args= -A
```

In any case though you need to make sure the host/vm accepts agent forwarding. In the remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` this has to be defined:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

Comment: Note that AllowAgentForwarding typically defaults to 'yes', but it's good to check that it isn't disabled for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

In the key_file option, you are using the public key when you should be using the private key

Source: http://docs.ansible.com/git_module.html

Comment: I tried private_key but it is not working. I edited my question with new findings.

Answer (score 1):

CheckOut [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/184#issuecomment-109653161).

It explains that `repo.git` ssh clone url should either be (URL syntax):

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_user/my_repo.git
```

or (SCP syntax):

```
git@bitbucket.org:my_user/my_repo.git
```

Check your `key_file` too.