# ansible git clone Permission denied issue

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant, ansible

I am trying to setup a dev environment using ansible and vagrant. Now i am stuck at cloning a git repo from bitbucket.

Below are Vagrantfile and ansible settings and things i have tried.

In my Vagrantfile i have `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`

In my deploy.yml i have

```
- name: ensure bitbucket is a known host
  lineinfile:
    dest: /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts
    create: yes
    state: present
    line: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -p 443 -t rsa altssh.bitbucket.org') }}"
    regexp: "^altssh\\.bitbucket\\.org"
  sudo_user: "vagrant"
  tags: known_hosts

- name: checkout opentest repo
  git: >
    dest="/home/vagrant/ot/"
    repo="ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/muhammadammar/opentest/"
    version="master"
    accept_hostkey=yes
  sudo_user: "vagrant"
  tags: checkout
```

First task above add bitbucket's public key into `/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Below is the output when ansible try to checkout the repo

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE git dest="/home/vagrant/ot/" repo="ssh:********@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/muhammadammar/opentest/" version=master accept_hostkey=yes
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/ammar/.ansible/cp/%h-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=2222 -o IdentityFile="/Users/ammar/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 127.0.0.1 /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -HE -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=vwkfotuvzzmllxvxptkgehjzdlqygoez] password: " -u vagrant /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-vwkfotuvzzmllxvxptkgehjzdlqygoez; LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python'"'"''
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote 'ssh:********@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/muhammadammar/opentest/' -h refs/heads/master", "failed": true, "rc": 128}
stderr: RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.174' not in list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

msg: RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.174' not in list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ammar/dev.retry

default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

On my host i have added my private key to ssh authentication agent. I can see private key identities using `ssh-add -l` on both host and on vagrant box.

In vagrant box i can successfully clone the repo using `git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/muhammadammar/opentest ot`

I am not sure what is the issue. Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

**EDIT**

Even the below is not working in ansible

```
shell: "git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/muhammadammar/opentest/ /home/vagrant/omp/"
```

Comment: did you try suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30775053/4296747 ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri not working

Answer (score 1):

Able to run `git clone ...` successfully on vagrant box isn't sufficient.

The way I see it, what's happening is:

- ansible tries to opens an ssh connection to vagrant box as user 'vagrant' (`User=vagrant`) and supplies the identity file: `-o IdentityFile="/Users/ammar/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"`
- executes `/bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -HE -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=vwkfotuvzzmllxvxptkgehjzdlqygoez] password: " -u vagrant /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-vwkfotuvzzmllxvxptkgehjzdlqygoez; LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python'"'"'`
- Tries to `git clone` using user '********' (`ssh:********@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/...)`

You should be able to do the same, ***are you?***

If not, then reasons can be many e.g.

- `/Users/ammar/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` isn't the correct file for user `vagrant`.
- `vagrant` isn't a sudoer.
- `vagrant@vagrant` user's key isn't registered with `********@altssh.bitbucket.org`

You'll know the correct reason after you've looked through the logs/output of all steps above.

**PS:** It seems redundant to use `sudo_user: vagrant` when you're already doing ssh using the same user. I can think of some reasons why one might do that, but at least here it is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately i don't know about anything from above because this is the first time i am looking into ansible and vagrant. I never thought that correctly configuring a vagrant box for git operations is complex and requires knowledge about lot of settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Are you using "sudo: yes" in your script? If you are, then the root user needs access to the repo, not the vagrant user.

Add the public key file of the root user to the Bitbucket account and you should be fine.

Alternatively you could do the checkout via your normal user.

In any case, the public key of the user accessing the repo within vagrant needs to be able to access Bitbucket.